# edit the etc\hosts file

Tags: c, windows, batch-file

Using C or a bat file, I'm trying to edit the file hosts file from c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc but I can;t bc it is write protected.

Can you tell me what can i do?

Comment: Are you using Windows Vista or newer? If so, UAC may be the problem. You need to run your application as an Administrator.

Comment: Admin isn't good enough, you need to elevate the rights of your program.  That requires a manifest.  A bit hard to come by for a C program, impossible for a bat file.  Don't hack the hosts file, it is security critical.

Comment: Why do you need to do it?  If you tell us the reason, somebody may be able to suggest a better solution e.g. DNS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program modifying the host file needs to run as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me what can i do?

Yes. Get the Administrator password or find another way to solve your problem.

If you describe what is your problem (rather than your issue on a possible solution) maybe we can figure a different (working) solution.

Comment: I'm the administrator. I can edit it if i run notepad as admin, but I wish to do it programatically. ty

Comment: @dole - you should edit your answer to add this bit of information there

Answer (score 0):

Open the file from VS code. VS code it self will show a dialog box. Confirm it.