# Editing HOSTS file on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, hosts

I'm writing an application that manages the hosts files entries. So I wrote a little code in C++ trying to access and read the HOSTS file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string line;
    fstream f ("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts");

    if ( f.is_open() )
    {
        while ( f.good() )
        {

            getline(f,line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }

        f.close();
    } else
        cout << "Error" << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Before making this question, i've read this one: [edit the etc\hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144342/edit-the-etc-hosts-file)

So, yes, I've tried running the program as admin, but it still doesn't work. How can my program read/edit the HOSTS running as admin?

Comment: `f.is_open()` returns false, indicating that `fstream f ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");` couldn't open the hosts file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you must *quote* backslashes in string literals. So try:

```
fstream f ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
```

This is because using a single backslash like `\n` means something special to the compiler.

Comment: indeed it has to be corrected. But still the program can't access hosts! :/

Comment: Ok, next thing to check is permissions. Normally non-admin users can't write to the hosts file, and `fstream` opens for reading *and* writing. What if you use `ifstream` instead of `fstream`, since you're only reading?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is you are using back slashes in the file path that are not escaped as `\\`?